# Is there any ideal time to complete Salah?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

Is there any ideal time to complete Salah like 4 rakkat in 15 minutes or ? Or anything like that ?

Comment: If you praying alone (Sunnah or nafl) then there is no such recommended time frame. If you are leading a prayer as an Imam then it is recommended to be mindful that there might be old people, sick people or even small children and the salah should not be unreasonably prolonged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specified time for prayer. However, the prayer should take as much time is needed to be performed in a way that doesn't make the performer in a rush or haste. Meaning: one should take his time between each segment action. Generally speaking: dhuhur prayer should take 5 to 10 minutes on average.